# Jquery Download File PlugIn Not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, download, resources, mp4

I want to download a file from server and once user completes dowload operation I want to remove it from server. So, for this purpose I am using the following Jquery plugin:

> fileDownload

The idea was that I will be deleting file on its call back functions. Below you can find the code snippet:

```
 $.fileDownload(url, {
                contentType: "application/octet-stream",
                contentDisposition: 'attachment; filename=' + response.fileName
               })
               .done(function () {
                    console.log('File download a success!');
                })
               .fail(function () {
                    console.log('File download failed!');
                });
```

So, when user tries to download the file, the following error occurs mainly:

1. It's call back functions are not working properly, each time **FAIL** call back function is called
2. Despite of FAIL call back, instead of downloading file, it starts playing that **MP4** file on browser window and I get the following error:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4.

So, Mainly there are **TWO** issues:

1. Each time **Fail** call back method is called
2. Recording started **PLAY** on browser instead of **Downloading**

Or, If there is any other alternative way to achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or, If there is any other alternative way to achieve this? thanks

Try using `XMLHttpRequest` with `responseType` set to `"blob"`

```
function refocus() {                     
  document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("download"));
  console.log("File download a success!");
  window.removeEventListener("focus", refocus)
}

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "/path/to/mp4", true); 
request.responseType = "blob";
request.onload = function (e) {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        // create `objectURL` of `this.response` : `.mp4` as `Blob`
        var file = URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = file;
        a.download = this.response.name || "file-" + new Date().getTime();
        a.id = "download";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        // remove `a` following `Save As` dialog, 
        // `window` regains `focus`
        window.addEventListener("focus", refocus, false);

    } else {
        console.log("File download failed!")
    }
};
request.send();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. This solution is working for me. There is some issue with 'onerror' call back as it doesn't seem working. I am giving url of file which doesn't exist on server but instead of error callback I am getting the following error on browser console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Try moving `console.log("File download failed!")` to `else` statement within `.onload`

Comment: thanks it worked. Can you please share the browser compatibility of this code?

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseen https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_compatibility , http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: great. Can you please share the purpose of adding eventlistener? as it works fine without listener as well? Is the purpose of this listener is just to remove the 'a' tag we created to download file?

Comment: @BilalAhmedYaseen _"Is the purpose of this listener is just to remove the 'a' tag we created to download file?"_ Yes. Using `.addEventListener` with named function as handler , can use `.removeEventListener` with name of function to remove

Comment: Furthermore, it opens a window each time to ask for location where it should download the file. Can't it download file directly without any prompt?

Comment: _"Furthermore, it opens a window each time to ask for location where it should download the file. Can't it download file directly without any prompt? "_  Is this were possible , any clicked link could download data directly to user filesystem

Comment: In order to download file directly what change would be required?

Comment: _"In order to download file directly what change would be required?"_ It is not possible to force user to download a file . Though preferences could be set at browser by user https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/957427

Comment: I'm getting some issues in understanding behavior of 'onFocus' event. So, I have the following questions:
(1) when this event is actually fired?
(2)  I wan to delete file from server after **successful** download, so at which part of above code I can be sure that file has been downloaded successfully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100037/discussion-between-bilal-ahmed-yaseen-and-guest271314).